# how to pass a number to a IEnumerable string as a parameter

Tags: c#, json, api

i have an api that i am trying to pass parametes through as follows:

```
Test: function (Product, Code, success, error, context) {

                    return API.http.get(API.methods.path + 'Test' {
                        Product: product,
                       Code:code //this is the problem that comes in.

                    }, success, error, context);
                },
```

So the Code gets a number back and i need to pass it as a string  to the bellow function:

```
public class Test : Query
    {
        public string product { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> code { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
```

however ***product*** gets passed through fine but the ***code*** doesnt get passed because its not a string.

so this is what i tried:

```
Test: function (Product, Code, success, error, context) {
                var codestring = '';
                (Code || []).forEach(g => {
                    if (codestring.length === 0)
                        codestring += '?code=' + Number(g);
                    else
                        codestring += '&code=' + Number(g);
                });
                return API.http.get(API.methods.path + 'Test' + codestring, {
                    Product: product

                }, success, error, context);
            },
```

Now the above ends up passing the **code** but the **Product** now doesnt get passed in it gets passed in as null.
what am i doing wrong? how do i pass the **code** in as a string?

Comment: So you're putting the product in the body and the code in the URL, and the code is passed fine as an enumerable and the product is not.. Or you've tried putting both in the body, and product is fine but code is not?

Comment: You probably just need to .map the Code array in your JavaScript into whatever form your API expects in the POST, and then put it in the request JSON as before. You'll need to check how your API expects to receive multiple codes and you should check the contents of the POST that your script it generating e.g. in your browser's debug tools to see if it matches or not.

Comment: Might also help to see the c# method you're calling (e.g. your controller method)

Comment: You should really look into some technology to automate this for you. Swagger comes to mind. Don't spend your time manually typing out your interface implementations, a tool can do that much better and free of errors.

Comment: @CaiusJard yes i put both in the body but the code doesnt get passed